# Get all websites, stores and store views in admin multi-select dropdown

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to retrieve all stores and store views for a given website id. The data is to be shown as a hierarchy in multi select dropdown in the admin form.
I tried using `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` to retrieve stores as follows:

`$storeData = $this->StoreManagerInterface->getStores();`

The above only gives the details about all the stores. But I am not able to retrieve stores through website Id.

Comment: Where you want to get this details?

Comment: In custom admin form multi-select dropdown.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inject class `Magento\Store\Model\System\Store` in the constructor.

```
protected $_systemStore;

public function __construct(
   ....
   \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
   ....
) {
  ....
  $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
  ....
}

protected function _prepareForm()
{
    ....
    $fieldset->addField(
       'store_ids',
       'multiselect',
       [
         'name'     => 'store_ids[]',
         'label'    => __('Store Views'),
         'title'    => __('Store Views'),
         'required' => true,
         'values'   => $this->_systemStore->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
       ]
    );
}
```

I hope it will helpful.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :)